# perl merge output and stderr and filter lines in windows

Tags: perl

I would like to run a external command in perl and filter some of the lines.
I don't know how to filter the lines that go to stderr. I have the following code right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use File::Spec;
#open STDERR, '>', File::Spec->devnull() or die "could not open STDERR: $!\n";

open(FILEHANDLE, '-|', 'Mycmd') or die "Cannot fork: $!\n";
open(STDERR, ">&FILEHANDLE");

while(defined(my $line = <FILEHANDLE>)) {
  chomp($line);
  if( $line =~ m/text1/ or
    $line =~ m/text2/ or
    $line =~ m/text3/
  ) {
    # do nothing
  }
  else {
    print "$line\n";
  }
}
close FILEHANDLE or die "child error: $!\n";
```

the line

```
open(STDERR, ">&FILEHANDLE");
```

is where I try to redirect the stderr to be able to process it with stdout but it doesn't work.

The solution would have to work in windows.

Comment: Did you close `STDERR` first? I don't think you can open a `FH` that is already open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell redirect in the argument to `open` can help here:

```
open(FILEHANDLE, 'Mycmd 2>&1 |') or die "Cannot fork: $!\n";
```

Now `FILEHANDLE` will see each line of both the standard output and the standard error from `Mycmd`.

To use multi-argument `open` *and* redirect output, you have to be more deliberate. Say `Mycmd` is

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
print "standard output\n";
warn  "standard error\n";
```

Opening `"-|"` gives us the standard output only, so if we run

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.0;

my $pid = open my $fh, "-|", "Mycmd" // die "$0: fork: $!";

while (defined(my $line = <$fh>)) {
  chomp $line;
  print "got [$line]\n";
}
```

The output is

```
standard error
got [standard output]
```

Notice that the standard output from `Mycmd` passed through the driver program but *not* its standard error. To get both, you have to mimic the shell’s redirection.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.0;

my $pid = open my $fh, "-|" // die "$0: fork: $!";

if ($pid == 0) {
  open STDERR, ">&STDOUT" or die "$0: dup: $!";
  exec "Mycmd"            or die "$0: exec: $!";
}

while (defined(my $line = <$fh>)) {
  chomp $line;
  print "got [$line]\n";
}
```

Now the output is

```
got [standard error]
got [standard output]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that this kinds of redirections would also work in windows, I am familiar with those in bash.

Comment: @skeept You're welcome! I'm glad it helps, and see the updated answer for performing the redirects yourself so you can bypass the shell's goofy argument parsing.